# Free developer ORG and Wave Analytics enabling

Tags: analytics

I was recently going through the Trail Heads for Admin Beginner with a new Free Developer ORG. When I was trying the Wave Analytics Module and try to enable related features in my existing Free Developer ORG but its not showing up. Then I created another one Free Developer account after clicking on the link mentioned in that module where I can see the Wave Analytics enabling and other related options.

Is there any difference between Normal Free Developer ORG and Wave Analytics enabled free Developer ORG? Just curious to know about this, let me know if someone have similar experience.

Thanks,
Robert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we have created a special developer org for Wave trailhead that have Wave license.